# How to make design for pagination like below image in datatable jquery

Tags: html, jquery, datatable, pagination

I want to make pagination like this image using datatable Jquery. Please help me to make like this.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YeIxY.png)

here is my code:

```
 $("#tblComplex").DataTable({
        "destroy": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "bRetrieve": true,
        "searching": false,
        "order": [0, "asc"],
        "pagingType": "simple",
        "dom": '<"wrapper"tilp>',
        "language": {
            "paginate": {
                "next": '<span><img src="images/next.svg" alt="next-arrow" /></span>',
                "previous": '<span><img src="images/previous.svg" alt="prev-arrow" /></span>'
            }
        },
        //"pageLength": 5,
        //"lengthMenu": [[5, 10, 20, -1], [5, 10, 20, 'Show All']],
        "ajax": {
            "url": "/Complex/GetComplexList",
            "type": "Post",
            "datatype": "json",
            "dataSrc": "complexListData"
        },
        "columns": [
            { "title": "Id", "data": "id", "orderable": true, "visible": false },
            {
                "title": "Name", "data": "name", "orderable": true, "visible": true },
            { "title": "Address", "data": "address", "orderable": true, "visible": true }
            
        ]
    });
```

Comment: specify the liberie you include. https://datatables.net/ i guess

Comment: @JulienMaret Maret,  Yes, I have used datatables.net library.

Comment: This link and css can help for your purpose: https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/dom.html

Comment: I already tried various way with link you provided. @Dani

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution.

we have to add just class name of css.
for example:

page 1 from 10

we have to define this in dom

"dom": '<"class1"<"class2"i>>